# How to implement a Factory with Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement a factory with Dagger2 but I don't know how?

In a simplified example:

```
public class Foo{

    public interface Factory{
        Foo createNew();
    }

    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar){
        this.bar= bar;
    }
}
```

I'd like to set a method that provides Foo.Factory instances

```
@Module
public class TestModule{
    @Provides
    Bar provideBar(){
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Provides
    Foo.Factory provideFooFactory(){
        // ??????
    }
}
```

The result should be something like (getting the Bar instance from the module of course):

```
new Foo.Factory(){
      @Override
      public Foo createNew() {
         return new Foo(new Bar());
      }
};
```

What is the correct approach to achieve this?

Comment: Why define a Factory interface if you can use the Provider in JSR330 which Dagger is comfortable with.

Comment: The documentation says not to use Provider except for legacy applications, that you should use a Factory pattern instead, but does not provide any example about how to actually do this with dagger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a working solution. Let me know if you have a better way

```
@Module
public class TestModule{
    @Provides
    Bar provideBar(){
        return new Bar();
    }
    @Provides
    Foo provideFoo(Bar bar){
        return new Foo(bar);
    }

    @Provides
    Foo.Factory provideFooFactory(final Provider<Foo> fooProvider){
        return  new Foo.Factory(){
                    @Override
                    public Foo createNew() {
                        return fooProvider.get();
                    }
        };
    }
}
```